# error in adding google play services as reference library in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

1>  When i add google play services library it shows **green right** mark but when i press ok and reopen      project properties its showing **red cross** mark.

2> In eclipse when i create new android project it by default creating activity which  ActionBarActivity insted of Activity. Why?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: ActionBarActivity is from AppCompat compatibility library. http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

Comment: shkschneider thank you for replying. How to restore it to just Activity ? and do you know anything about question 1 ?

Comment: 2. Why would you take compatibility off? 1. Post a screenshot please

Comment: For 1. Ensure that the path to the library is correct. And the library is actually there. You will get a red cross if you arent referring to the library correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution

*copy google-play-services-lib and paste it in other location.
*change eclipse workspace.
* Importe google-play-services-lib as Existing Android Code Into Workspace. browse to new location and select google-play-services-lib folder.
* Goto project properties->android->Add  and select google-play-services-lib.